# equivalent of browserField.displayContent() in javascript

Tags: javascript, blackberry, cordova, blackberry-webworks

I tried to create my own app for BlackBerry using BlackBerry workflow SDK and phonegap.

I have a web service which sends html code and I need to use this code in a new window. I tried
window.document.write('test'); But when I use the back button on the phone, the application just quits.

Resolution without html code but url :

```
//Invoke blackberry browser
var args = new blackberry.invoke.BrowserArguments(url); 
blackberry.invoke.invoke(blackberry.invoke.APP_BROWSER, args);
```

Answer (score 1):

BlackBerry WebWorks only has one window. You will need to work with that. 
So, There are a couple ways you can do what I think you're looking to achieve.

1 - If you just need to show the new html and you dont care about the back button working you can just insert the html into the current page

```
document.querySelector("body").innerHTML = htmldata;
```

2 - If you need the back button to will need to save the htmlData to localStorage and change pages, then load the stored html.

```
localStorage.setItem("htmldata", htmlData);
window.location.href = "page2.html";
document.querySelector("body").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("htmldata");;
```

**EDIT**

3 - Trap hardware key

```
blackberry.system.event.onHardwareKey(blackberry.system.event.KEY_BACK, handleBack);

function handleBack() {
  alert("handle back button");
}
```

Comment: Hi and thx for you answer ! Now i'm trying to use something like window.location.href = "http://google.fr"; But when i use the blackberry back button my app just quit... so if there is no other solution i will try your's :)

Comment: I try your solution : in page index.html =>    localStorage.setItem("url", url);
window.location.href = "webView.html";                And in page webView.html =>                                 function init() {
   var url = localStorage.getItem("url");
   window.location.replace(url);                                     }  But same result "back button" quits application...

Comment: I just added an option 3, try that.

Comment: Thans for your answer. I already try something like option 3, but same result. I solve my problem with :        var args = new blackberry.invoke.BrowserArguments(url);    blackberry.invoke.invoke(blackberry.invoke.APP_BROWSER, args);